# Running cucumber for iOS in jenkins job fails with Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))

Tags: ios, jenkins, cucumber, ios-simulator

I run a jenkins box (OS X yosemitee and xcode6.1, jenkins 1.586, cucumber 0.11) and one of the step of the job is to run cucumber.

The script is (another script before that delete the derived data folder):

```
#build calabash version of app
~/.jenkins/userContent/externalTools/xctool/bin/xctool \
    -workspace elektra.xcworkspace \
    -scheme "elektra-cal" \
    -configuration Debug_Dogfish \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -reporter plain \
    build 

#if the build failed, get out
buildResult=$?
if [ "$buildResult" != "0" ]; then
    exit $buildResult
fi

#run calabash tests
mkdir -p ../../build/cucumberTests/
killall "iOS Simulator"

cucumber DEBUG=1 test/cucumber -f junit -o ../../build/cucumberTests/ --tags @working -v || :
```

And i get the following error (note that if i run the same commands from the command line directly, things work great)

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Code:
  * test/cucumber/support/env.rb
  * test/cucumber/support/01_launch.rb
  * test/cucumber/support/hooks.rb
  * test/cucumber/support/support.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/capture.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/create_account.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/equipment.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/global.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/history.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/login_steps.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/resource_center.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/team.rb
  * test/cucumber/step_definitions/work_orders.rb

Features:
  * test/cucumber/Capture.feature
  * test/cucumber/Create_Account.feature
  * test/cucumber/Equipment.feature
  * test/cucumber/History.feature
  * test/cucumber/Login.feature
  * test/cucumber/Resource_Center.feature
  * test/cucumber/Settings.feature
  * test/cucumber/Team.feature
  * test/cucumber/Work_Orders.feature
Parsing feature files took 0m0.079s
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
[32m
INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'[0m
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
```

Any idea as to why this is not working?

Comment: Agreed. But why is it not running? Why running the same commands to launch it from within Jenkins fail, when they succeed on the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on te iOS-calabash forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/0s1ZmFrgXP4

Need to add 
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
to shell script job in jenkins

Comment: worked for some people on google groups, but not me. Drives me bonkers because if i wipe derived data and build for an older sim iPhone 5s 7.1 it works, and if wipe again and build for iPhone 6 8.4 I get a NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there is nothing listening on TCP port 37265 on your local machine.  I'm not terribly familiar with calabash itself, but you should certainly start there.  My initial guess is that you don't have the calabash server running in order to submit your tests to it for testing.